# getting registry entry and then adding to it

Tags: powershell, registry

I am trying to get a registry key value , ExtensionSettings, if there is something in the registry then save it. Then add a new entry to it . The two entries have to have a comma in-between values. I can not figure the code out . I am not sure what I am doing wrong or missing. Thank you so much for your help.

```
# Set variables to indicate value and key to set
$RegistryPath = 'HKLM:SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome'
$Name         = 'ExtensionSettings'
$Value        = '{"feolagkacappiaieohahjkeaikhjjcfa":{"toolbar_pin":"force_pinned"}}'

# Create the key if it does not exist
If (-NOT (Test-Path $RegistryPath)) {
  New-Item -Path $RegistryPath -Force | Out-Null
}  

#$OldValue = Get-ItemProperty -Path $RegistryPath -Name $Name 
#$oldValue = $OldValue.ExtensionSettings

$OldValue = (Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome").ExtensionSettings
#$NewValue = New-ItemProperty -Path $RegistryPath -Name $Name -Value $value
$UpdatedValue =  $OldValue + "," + $NewValue

$NewValue = $NewValue.ExtensionSettings


New-ItemProperty -Path $RegistryPath -Name $Name -Value $UpdatedValue -PropertyType String -Force
```

Here is the error I get. I have updated the code with what I have tried . Nothing is written to the registry key. It goes show the comma but not the rest.

error I receive is

```
    New-ItemProperty : The property already exists.
At line:15 char:13
+ $NewValue = New-ItemProperty -Path $RegistryPath -Name $Name -Value $ ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceExists: (HKEY_LOCAL_MACH...s\Google\Chrome:String) [New-ItemProperty], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.IOException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemPropertyCommand
```

Comment: at this point >>> `$UpdatedValue =  $OldValue + "," + $NewValue` <<< you have not defined the `$NewValue` that you are trying to use.. [*grin*]

Comment: the new value I have comment out. I tried to use that and it did not work. I should have said that. The new value should be defined as what is the top variables.  I t\ried that with it in and would not work. It kept saying already set.

Comment: ok! [*grin*]  next, add that info to your Question ... and also add  the full text of any error msgs you rcvd.

Comment: my apologies. I have updated the original question

Comment: so, have you tried `Set-ItemProperty` instead of  `New-ItemProperty`?

Comment: yes. I have tried both. It still produces the same error. I did look and newvalue is not getting passed anything. But if I run the command by itself then it is set .

Comment: i am out of ideas. [*sigh ...*] i recommend you add that info to your Question and hope that someone who understands the situation notices ... and helps. i wish you good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The "Extension Settings" registry key is a JSON-formatted string, so you won't be able to simply concatenate on to the end of it.  Here's a sample string that Google provides as an example . . . notice that *the entire string is encapsulated in curly braces*.  In order to add an entry, you'd have to add it *inside* the outer set of curly braces.

```
{
   "*": {
    "installation_mode": "blocked"
  }, 
  "nckgahadagoaajjgafhacjanaoiihapd": {
    "installation_mode": "force_installed",
      "update_url":
      "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx"
  },
  "lpcaedmchfhocbbapmcbpinfpgnhiddi": {
    "installation_mode": "normal_installed",
    "update_url":
       "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx"
  },
  "gmbgaklkmjakoegficnlkhebmhkjfich": {
    "installation_mode": "allowed"
  }
}
```

Something like the following should work (note that the original $Value has been modified to remove the outer curly braces):

```
# Set variables to indicate value and key to set
$RegistryPath = 'HKLM:SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome'
$Key         = 'ExtensionSettings'
$ValueAdd     = '"feolagkacappiaieohahjkeaikhjjcfa":{"toolbar_pin":"force_pinned"}'

# Check for existing 'ExtensionSettings' key and modify/create
If ((Get-Item -Path $RegistryPath).GetValue($Key) -ne $null) {
  # Copy existing value (without outer braces)
    $string = (Get-ItemProperty "$RegistryPath").$Name
    $ValueOld = $string.subString(1, ($string.Length)-2)
  # Modify to add new value (and add outer braces)
    $ValueNew = "{$ValueOld, $ValueAdd}"
    New-ItemProperty -Path $RegistryPath -Name $Key -Value $ValueNew -PropertyType String -Force
} else {
  # If it doesn't already exist, create it
  $ValueNew = "{$ValueAdd}"
  New-ItemProperty -Path $RegistryPath -Name $Key -Value $ValueNew -PropertyType String -Force
}
```